# Escaping html only in specific columns for a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas

Is it possible for a pandas dataframe to escape only certain column(s) when converting to an html table?

Originally there was only one column with an html embedded link, so when I converted my df to a html table I used df.to_html(escaped = False), which returned the result I was looking for.

But now there is another column in the table with html as well but here I only want it to be read as text. Is this possible with the to_html() function?

Comment: I would do two passes: one to escape the columns that need to be so, then the to_html call as you do

Comment: Thanks @Boud. That would have made sense to try first. It worked

Comment: It's actually escape=False, not escaped